# Why Import-CSV "names.csv" | Where { $_.Id } not working?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am working with this [CSV](https://ulearn.me/Courses/testingcasting/Casting.Course/slides/04_ScriptTask/names.csv) file and the `Import-CSV "names.csv" | Where { $_.Id }` gives nothing. Tell me why?

I want to choose from this file those lines in which the value of the name column is more than 15 characters, then put the data in the result.txt in the following format:

name1, age1
name2, age2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the delimiter of a semi-colon (;) not being specified, that is one reason.  This should help get you started hopefully.

```
$Names=Import-CSV "names.csv" -Delimiter ';'

ForEach ($Name in $Names) {
    If ($Name.Name.Length -gt 14) {
        $FoundMatch=("$($Name.Name)","$($Name.Age)") -Join ','
        Out-File -FilePath 'test.txt' -InputObject $FoundMatch -Append
    }
}
```